# Django - how to display related many-to-many field in choice field?

Tags: django, django-models

I’m building a web app using Django for my music collection. For each album, there are multiple songs, and each song has one or more composers. Here’s the song model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    composer = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
    
    def __str__ (self):
        return self.title
```

The `Artist` model contains `firstname` and `lastname` fields.

There are a number of occurrences of songs with the same title, and the only way to distinguish between them is by the composer. Currently, when songs are loaded into a choice field, only the title appears, using `__str__()` method. I’ve tried to include the composers, but haven’t found a way to make it work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to somehow insert the composers' names into the `Song`'s `__str__` method.

One way to do this is by fetching the first and last names of the composers and formatting them before displaying in the `__str__`. Take the following example:

```py
def __str__(self):
   raw_composers = self.composers.values_list("first_name", "last_name")
   stringified_composers = [f"{first_name} {last_name}" for (first_name, last_name) in raw_composers]
   formatted_composers = ", ".join(stringified_composers)
   return f"{self.title} ({formatted_composers})"
```

While this does work, the Django admin pages that display these choices will be doing lots of queries (namely, N queries for each Song of the list, where N is the amount of Artists related to this song).
Be sure to run a `.prefetch_related(...)` to speed things up a little!

Comment: Thanks for the response. As you suggested, it takes a while to execute. There are more than 8000 songs, so probably 10-12000 composers. I'm interested to try the prefetch suggestion, but don't know where to insert it. I'm quite new to Django, if you couldn't tell.

Comment: In your `SongAdmin` class, override the `def get_queryset(self, request)` method. Make it return: `return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related("composer")`. With this implementation, you'll "pre" fetch all the `Artist`s related to your `Song`s, instead of making 1 query for each Song.

Tip for using these optimizations:
- If you have a `ManyToMany` relationship, use `.prefetch_related(...)`
- If you are in the "child" side of  a `ForeignKey`, use `.select_related(...)`

Here's the official docs for it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Thanks again. The prefetch helped - reduced the time to load the Song choicefield from 35 seconds to about 20 seconds. Better, but still not usable. I'll try a different approach.